# Possible to configure Weceem to upload content to database or S3 instead of local server file system?

Tags: grails, weceem

I'd like to give our business team the ability to edit certain pages and content themselves via a CMS solution in our grails application, and [Weceem](http://grails.org/plugin/weceem) plugin seems like a good choice.

The potential showstopper I see is that is uses the local server file system for uploaded content, which is no good in a horizontally scaled cloud environment like ours (we run in AWS).

Question is, is it possible to tell Weceem to use the database to store binary/uploaded content, or (better yet) override the content upload handlers to use Amazon S3 instead of the file system (we already have code that uploads to S3 in our main app, so the question is just how to hook into Weceem)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in such situation its possible to create your own content type (domain class) in your app that stores binary uploaded content. This class should be a subclass of org.weceem.content.WcmContent class. In weceem you can check a small example for storing such content, see [org.weceem.files.WcmContentFileDB class](https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/domain/org/weceem/files/WcmContentFileDB.groovy) Also, [here](http://jcatalog.github.io/weceem-plugin/guide/customization.html#1.CreateCustomContentTypes) there is an information how to extend plugin with custom content type. I hope the information can be helpful.

As for uploading: in Weceem we use CKeditor plugin for uploading additional files/resources, also org.weceem.files.WcmContentFile is used, it stores files on file system, the files are uploaded using paths provided with *org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.getUploadPath(...)* method. This path is calculated from configuration property that is provided in application config (e.g. 'weceem.upload.dir'). Not sure that you can hook here.

Comment: It seems like I should probably create a pull request that adds S3 upload capability - or is someone already working on this?

Comment: Currently there is no activity in this area, but your pull request with contribution is very appreciated.